# At what point can the government limit your 1st amendment right to free speech?

Tags: united-states, freedom-of-speech

Bill is a retired U.S. naval intelligence officer. He is very knowledgeable on the history of U.S. government oppression and state sponsored terrorism. He likes to spend his free time walking around in public and preaching about all the terrible acts the government and their agencies have done to its own citizens and other people around the world.

He usually follows a routine of going to the same place, at the same time, every week. Eventually, he starts to garner a following of folks who like to hear him talk and they come out at the same time he does. This ends up growing into a very large and noticeable crowd every time he comes out in public. Due to size, The police start telling people to disperse. Bill refuses to leave as he is not breaking the law. Bill starts saying "*See this is an example of government oppression!*" This incites the crowd and they start getting agitated. So the police arrest Bill for "Inciting a riot".

The Police have reached their limit with Bill and start saying it is an unlawful assembly every time he comes out to speak.

Every time Bill comes out to speak;

- He never incites violence
- He never tells people to do anything
- He never uses amplified devices
- He is always in a forum of public expression like city hall.
- It is always in the middle of the day

---

### At what point can the government limit Bill's 1st amendment right to free speech?

Comment: Municipalities usually have a permit requirement for large gatherings.  Does Bill have a permit for his gatherings, and is he complying with its terms as to size, time, place, frequency, etc?

Comment: He is simply walking around and talking. He has no intention of gathering people. They gather on their own free will. He doesn't post schedules or events. He simply walks around because its good for his health at his age.

Comment: If Bill knows he is gathering large crowds when he stops and speaks, he fits all the necessary intention required by law.  It's not like there's any way he could prove he didn't intend to do something that he knew he would do by his acts.

Comment: Why would Bill have to prove that he lacked intent. On whom rests the burden of proof?

Comment: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/23202/can-the-city-of-charlottesville-va-ban-a-group-from-assembling-in-the-town-beca and https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/61326/at-what-point-does-peaceably-in-the-first-amendment-not-apply-with-regard-to-u/61328

Comment: @Mary What do you understand the criteria for intention to be? Bill does not meet the common law or MPC definitions.

Comment: @NateEldredge sounds like a freedom of association violation

Comment: @user253751: [Time place and manner restrictions](https://www.mtsu.edu/first-amendment/article/1023/time-place-and-manner-restrictions) are constitutional if they are narrowly tailored, applied content-neutrally, and allow alternative channels.

Comment: @NateEldredge Permits are generally used to help the municipalities coordinate such things as "road closures or access to property or resources that might not ordinarily be used to large crowds of people."  There's little that the cities can do to stop people from just coming to a public site that is not a place of government business and talking about things they want to talk about, so long as it's peacefully done.   Disturbing the peace charges may be part of "Time Manner Place" restrictions.

Comment: On the general, Bill's specific words and the context of them are going to be looked at as to what a reasonable person would understand them to mean as well as Bill's intent.  If Bill makes a call to action that is an imminent lawless action (I.e. "I say we give the government hell until they listen" is perfectly fine as the intent and specific literal actions are easy to construe into more peaceful protest while "I say we grab our torches and pitchforks and run wild through the city!" pretty much removes all doubt as to what Bill wants.)

Comment: @Mary So ... if you don't like someone and want them to be arrested every time they leave their house, all you have to do is get a thousand people to follow them around? Sounds rather akin to the heckler's veto.

Comment: @Acccumulation  Provided you don't mind that it's you who get arrested for harassment.

Comment: Isn't the answer to this question simply "at no point"? The First Amendment says *"Congress shall make no law ... abridging the freedom of speech"*, not *"Congress shall make no law, except ..."*. The thing is that the First Amendment doesn't give you every conceivable right, and Congress *may* pass laws which abridge rights not guaranteed by the First Amendment. So the point at which they can limit your speech is the point at which your speech is not protected by the First Amendment, and the real question is at what point the First Amendment ceases to protect you. But that's rather broad.

Comment: @kaya3 You forget the 9th which state that the Bill of Rights is not the definitive list of rights, and that Congress should not infringe on a right on the basis that the Constitution doesn't say it's a right.  The 10th Amendment limits the Federal Government further by saying that any right or power not explicitly listed as a right or power of the Federal Government is to be devolved to the State Governments or the people.